# Making my domain show up instead of my sitemap.xml in Google search results

Tags: seo, google, search-results, xml-sitemap

If I search Google for a term or my site name, Google returns the URL `sitename.com/sitemap.xml` on the first or second page of the results.

*I want the main site to return in the results and not the sitemap*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the *sitemap.xml* file from your SERP, follow the steps outlined here: [Google Webmaster Tools - Completely remove an entire page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419)

To prevent this from being indexed again, add `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` to the header response for the URL to your *sitemap.xml* in your web server configuration, as indicated [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag).

An example for a `.htaccess` file for Apache would be:

```
<FilesMatch "sitemap\.xml">
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: It is indexed for the keyword, so that's a matter of SEO to get it to rank higher. Have a look on this site for how to improve your SEO and rank in Google, like [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google) question.

Comment: @Octavian Ristea Thanks - one thing I noticed looking at your site regarding SEO is that the term "Hipholic" only appears in the title of your home page and is not visible in the content. If you want to be ranked higher, your content should reflect what you're trying to be ranked for - so it might be a good idea to add that to your visible content.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same exact thing. I just don't know where to put the keyword Hipholic on the homepage right now. I have it in the footer, but I'm not sure where to make room for it in the content.

If I add "Hipholic" in the same place as "Mixtapes" on this page http://hipholic.com/category/mixtapes/ to the homepage, then it would be a bit repetitive. The logo would say "Hipholic" and then so would the text right under it.